# Change the xml attribute name in

Tags: c#, xml

How can i change the XElement attribute name in c#?

So if

```
<text align="center"> d hhdohd  </text>
```

after change the attribute name align to text-align

```
<text text-align="center> d hhdohd  </text>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `[XmlAttribute(Name=)]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `LINQ-XML`, you can remove an `existing` attribute and then add a new one.

Xml markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <text align="center" other="attribute">Something</text>
</root>
```

Code:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
 var element = doc.Root.Element("text");
 var attList = element.Attributes().ToList();
 var oldAtt = attList.Where(p => p.Name == "align").SingleOrDefault();
 if (oldAtt != null)
  {
   XAttribute newAtt = new XAttribute("text-align", oldAtt.Value);
   attList.Add(newAtt);
   attList.Remove(oldAtt);
   element.ReplaceAttributes(attList);
   doc.Save(file);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `XmlElement SetAttribute` and `RemoveAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to remove and re-add, not sure the syntax off the top of my head.  but you should be able to xpath to the  node.  Capture the value of the existing attribute, remove the attribute, create a new attribute and assign it the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Using [linq-to-xml](/questions/tagged/linq-to-xml), you can use [`XElement.ReplaceAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replaceattributes.aspx) method to update the xml attributes, something like this:

```
XElement data = XElement.Parse (@"<text align=""center""> d hhdohd  </text>");

data.ReplaceAttributes(
    new XAttribute("text-align", "center")
);
```